# Finding most frequent value char in matrix in R error

Tags: r, matrix, row

I have the following matrix:

```
> a
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,] "F"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "M"  "F"  "I"  "I"  NULL NULL 
  [2,] "M"  "M"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "M"  "M"  NULL 
  [3,] "M"  "M"  NULL "M"  "F"  "M"  NULL "M"  "M"  "M"  
  [4,] "M"  "F"  "M"  "M"  "F"  "F"  "M"  "M"  "F"  "F"  
  [5,] "M"  "I"  NULL "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  
  [6,] "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  "M"  NULL "I"  "I"  "M"  "M"  
  [7,] "I"  "I"  "I"  "I"  NULL "I"  "F"  "I"  "I"  "I"  
  [8,] "I"  "I"  NULL "I"  "F"  "I"  "F"  "I"  "I"  "I"  
  [9,] "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "F"  "F"  NULL "M"  "F"  "M"  
 [10,] NULL "F"  NULL "F"  "F"  "F"  "M"  "F"  "F"  "F"  
 [11,] NULL "M"  NULL "F"  "F"  "M"  NULL "M"  "F"  "M"  
 [12,] "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"  NULL "F"  "M"  "F"  "M"  
 [13,] "I"  NULL "M"  "F"  NULL "F"  "M"  NULL "M"  "F"  
...
```

I would like to add a column that will include the most common characters (NULLs can be ignored) per row (line). For instance for row 1 and 2 the answer is `"I"`. For line 3 - `"M"` etc.
I tried to use

```
> max.col (a)
Error in max.col(a) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

> str (a)
List of 8360
 $ : chr "F"
 $ : chr "M"
 $ : chr "M"
 $ : chr "M"
...
 $ : chr "I"
 $ : chr "F"
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 836 10

> class (a)
[1] "matrix"
```

Even tried this:

```
 g <- function(df)
    {
      X <- as.data.frame(t(apply( df, 1,
                                  function(row)
                                  {
                                    u <- unique(row)
                                    n <- rowSums(outer(u,row,"=="))
                                    if (length(u)==1 )
                                    {
                                      c(row,u[which.max(n)],max(n),"",0)
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                      c(row,u[which.max(n)],max(n),u[which.min(n)],min(n))
                                    }
                                  })))  

      colnames(X) <- c(colnames(df),"max_res","max_num","min_res","min_num")

      return(X)
    }
    a<-data.frame(a)
    g1<-g(a)
```

got:

```
 Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : comparison of these types is not implemented 

> dput(head(a, 10))
structure(list("F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "I", "I", "I", "M", NULL, 
    "I", "M", "M", "F", "I", "I", "I", "I", "M", "F", "I", "I", 
    NULL, "M", NULL, "I", "I", NULL, "M", NULL, "I", "I", "M", 
    "M", "I", "I", "I", "I", "M", "F", "M", "I", "F", "F", "I", 
    "M", NULL, "F", "F", "F", "F", "I", "M", "F", "I", NULL, 
    "I", "I", "F", "F", "I", "I", NULL, "M", "I", "I", "F", "F", 
    NULL, "M", "I", "M", "M", "M", "I", "I", "I", "I", "M", "F", 
    NULL, "M", "M", "F", "I", "M", "I", "I", "F", "F", NULL, 
    NULL, "M", "F", "I", "M", "I", "I", "M", "F"), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L))
> dput (a)
structure(list("F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "I", "I", "I", "M", NULL, 
    NULL, "M", "I", "F", "I", "F", NULL, NULL, "F", "I", "F", 
    NULL, "F", "I", NULL, "F", "F", "F", "I", "M", "F", "F", 
    NULL, "I", NULL, "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "I", "I", 
    "M", "F", "M", "I", "I", "F", "I", "M", "F", "M", "M", "I", 
    "I", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "I", "F", "F", "F", "M", "I", 
    "I", "I", "I", "F", "I", "I", "I", "M", "I", NULL, "M", "M", 
    "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", NULL, NULL, "I", "M", 
    "I", "I", NULL, NULL, "F", NULL, NULL, "I", "F", "F", "F", 
    "I", "I", NULL, "M", "M", "I", "I", "I", "F", "M", "I", "F", 
    "M", "F", "M", NULL, "M", "F", "I", "M", "I", NULL, "I", 
    "M", "I", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
...
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL), .Dim = c(836L, 10L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example

Comment: I added dput to question.

Comment: There is some issue in the `dput` output.  Can you test it on your console.  The issue is that it is incomplete `... `.  Incomplete structure won't work.  Use only a small data and dput i.e. `dput(head(a, 10))`

Comment: Please use `dput` on a subset of `a` with fewer rows. The error is caused by the ellipsis (`...`) where rows are omitted.

Comment: Added  dput(head(a, 10))

Comment: Try this `table(unlist(lapply(a, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for your `dput(head(a, 10))`.

```
apply(X = a, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){
    x = x[!sapply(x, is.null)]
    with(data = as.data.frame(table(unlist(x))),
         expr = toString(Var1[which(Freq == max(Freq))]))
})
# [1] "I"    "I"    "M"    "F, M" "I"    "I"    "I"    "I"    "M"    "F"
```

If you want only one character from each row use

```
apply(X = a, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){
    x = x[!sapply(x, is.null)]
    with(data = as.data.frame(table(unlist(x))),
         expr = toString(Var1[which.max(Freq)]))
})
# [1] "I" "I" "M" "F" "I" "I" "I" "I" "M" "F"
```

Comment: I got the following error:  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Var1' not found

Comment: Be careful because you can have a tie. You must think about what to do in that case.

Comment: I want to see only one value. If 2 are the same quantity randomly select or first one. Instead of NULL you can insert the most common value of all the matrix.